# How to resolve the error of this Shell Commands in JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, pandas

```
!cat datasets/Admission_Predict.csv


ERROR:
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`%bash`**](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics) then following UNIX command in your case `cat`

```
%bash cat your_file.extension
```

If you want to execute multiple lines then use [**`%%bash`**](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cell-magics)

```
%%bash
cmd 1
cmd 2
...
cmd n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `!more datasets/Admission_Predict.csv`